# Unable to run py2 virtual environment in command line

Tags: python, cmd, virtualenv

I'm trying to run a script (from udacity lesson quiz) which was written in python 2. The course instruction recommends using python 2.6 or 2.7 so I created a virtual environment in anaconda prompt using *conda create --name py2 python=2.7* and then installed the required libraries using pip. After activating the py2 environment (version 2.7.18) I tried running a script from the lesson in both atom editor and anaconda prompt and i got SyntaxError in both cases. The error messages look like this:

***for Anaconda prompt i got this:***

(py2) C:\Users\fayolpc\Desktop\ml-mini-project\ud120-projects>python tools/startup.py

```
    checking for nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/startup.py", line 6, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\PYTHON\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "C:\PYTHON\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 35, in <module>
    from nltk.probability import FreqDist
  File "C:\PYTHON\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 333
    print("%*s" % (width, samples[i]), end=" ")
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

***for atom editor i got this:***

```
 File "C:\Users\fayolpc\Desktop\ml-mini-project\ud120-projects\tools\startup.py", line 4
    print "checking for nltk"
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("checking for nltk")?
```

I can't figure out what the problem is and I have done a lot of searching for solution but can't find any. I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me out. By the way I'm new to both programming and this community. Thanks for considering to help.

Comment: Are you certain you are using Python2.7?  If it's giving you a syntax error with the print, I'm hazarding a guess that you're using some other python version > 2.7.

Comment: The python version showing is 2.7.18.

Comment: The code `print("%*s" % (width, samples[i]), end=" ")` is definitely for Python 3; it seems you've installed a wrong version of `nltk`. And this `print "checking for nltk"` is definitely for Python 2 but executed under Python 3; it seems your `atom` uses Python 3.

Comment: Alright thanks for pointing that out. The thing is that I initially installed python via anaconda which I presume pre-installed nltk and a bunch of other data science libraries. Now on creating py2 environment I installed nltk and sklearn again under this python version. I don't know if this has something to do with the issue I'm having. Meanwhile I'll have to go figure out what python version my atom editor is running as u mentioned and to see if switching to python 2 (If there's anything like that) will fix it. Thanks once more.